# Download m3u file with wget

Tags: python

I want to download an m3u file but unfortunately I get the 404 error
on Firefox but when I refresh the page the download starts:

```
import os
url = 'https://watch.xpsclub.com:2083/get.php?username=FOO&password=XXX&output=ts&type=m3u_plus'   
M3UPATH= '/tmp/IPTVWORLD55.m3u'     
def create_bouquet():
    if not os.path.exists(M3UPATH):
        #os.system('wget --no-check-certificate -q -O- --trust-server-names %s > %s' % (url, M3UPATH))
        #os.system('curl -c --limit-rate 50K %s -o %s' % (url, M3UPATH))
        os.system('curl -H "Accept-Charset: utf-8" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --limit-rate 100K %s -o %s' % (url, M3UPATH))

create_bouquet()

###########################################################################
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Comment: You should think twice about giving out your username and password publicly (i.e. in the url in the question) ... if they were your real private credentials you should change your password now!

Comment: is this part `if not os.path.exists(M3UPATH):` supposed to be inside the for loop?  otherwise you will only load the last `url` found in the file

Comment: the line and 1 day free

Comment: The response headers I am getting for that URL in my browser indicate that CloudFlare is involved - so this might simply be due to some sort of "bot protection".

Answer (score 0):

You can use build_opener and install_opener .. this is simple code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

try:
    from urllib import urlretrieve as compat_urlretrieve # PY2
    from urllib2 import build_opener as compat_build_opener
    from urllib2 import install_opener as compat_install_opener
except:
    from urllib.request import urlretrieve as compat_urlretrieve  # PY3
    from urllib.request import build_opener as compat_build_opener
    from urllib.request import install_opener as compat_install_opener

M3UPATH ='/home/Desktop/M3UPATH.m3u' 
url = 'https://watch.xpsclub.com:2083/get.php?username=30I8C1TOKJ&password=YSNK81BU6V&output=ts&type=m3u_plus'

opener = compat_build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'), ('Accept','text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'), ('Accept-Encoding','gzip, deflate, br'),\
    ('Accept-Language','en-US,en;q=0.5' ), ("Connection", "keep-alive"), ("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests",'1')]
compat_install_opener(opener)
compat_urlretrieve(url, M3UPATH)
```